# Как создать единый проект в Intelij IDEA для Spring и Vue-cli?

Tags: spring, vue.js, intellij-idea, vue-cli

Не знаю как правильно начать. Как правильно инициализировать пустой проект, который одновременно использует Spring для backend и Vue-cli для frontend.

Все источники, какие находил по использованию Vue вместе со Spring показывают, как через cdn добавить Vue к index.html.

Видел как отдельно настроить webpack, babel, npm и соответсвенно в каталогах Maven src/static/ src/tempalate размещать файлы Vue, но в этом случае мы не используем Vue-cli.

Ни как не могу найти, как добавить Vue используя Vue-cli.

Пока у меня следующие предположения:

1. Просто находясь в корне моего проекта Maven/Spring написать

```
vue create NewProject
```

И тогда у меня получится Vue проект вложенный в Spring. Следовательно если я захочу из консоли запускать команды для Spring и для Vue-cli мне нужно будет постоянно переходить между корнем и вложенной папкой для Vue-cli

2. Создать два отдельный проекта, один для Vue-cli, другой для Sring.

Тогда я должен буду работать в одновременно в двух экземплярах среды разработки.

Comment: ну вообще по хорошему и репозитория должно быть 2, но если есть необходимость такого подхода, то первый вариант выглядит правильным.

Comment: Мне интересно как правильно. Правильно создать два раздельных проекта? И отдельно работать с каждым? Как я понимаю во время разработки у меня в любом случае будет запускаться два сервера на одном будет раздаваться Vue-cli, на другом Spring приложение оба сервера будут работать на разных портах. Потом когда будет сборка будет сформирован js файл, который будет содержать весь код для Vue и этот js я должен буду положить в свой проект Spring

Comment: Ну у меня на проекте ангуляр примерно также развёрнут, он сам лежит в папке src/main/frontend а конфиги вынесены на рутовую папку, при запуске дев сервера работает прокси, а при сборке npm run build, файлы помещаются в static

Comment: @Komdosh А не подскажете такой момент, по backend'у. Когда я начинал делать приложение используя Thymeleaf в качестве SSR я делал для сущностей DTO которые уже помещал в модель. Нужно ли в случае REST приложения реализовывать DTO? Эта архитектура сохранется и в этом случае?

Comment: ну DTO это будут json объекты, которыми перекидываться будете

Comment: Понятно, а дальше как и раньше mapper из DTO в Entity и обратно. Я, кстати, придумал как сделать два проекта в одном. Можно использовать Модули, где один модуль можно назвать client(или frontend), а другой server (или backend). И все будет в одном окне и раздельные репозитарии.

Comment: @AlexanderLopatin у меня в проекте так и сделано: 2 модуля, backend для сервера (spring boot приложение) и frontend для фронта на vue. Удобно работать. Но для деплоя разделил проект на 2 отдельных соответственно этим 2 модулям.

Answer (score 0):

Правильного варианта нет. Есть удобные и не удобные варианты. И да, это все вкусовщина, кто как привык. Делать можно как угодно, система Вам этого не запрещает. Делайте, как удобно Вам. Если Вы в проекте не один, то надо договориться с коллегами о варианте, который будет удобен всем.